# Visual Basic random number for multiple variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Goal: To make a game were a user will select from 16 different options and receive 16 unique responses. These responses are simple security tips for user training.

They must be in random order so nobody can screen look and predict which button yields which result and they cannot be reused/duplicate responses during a single game.

I have been going back and forth on either to use an array or the select case. The select case is looking more promising, however I am not sure how to assign, randomly, 16 different buttons to provide the correct not repeating responses.

Poor code as requested,

```
        'Create Select Case random value and assign to buttons
    Do
        btn2 = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd()) + 1))
        'lblDescript so I can see what btn2 is outputting
        lblDescript.Text = btn2.ToString
    Loop While btn2 <> btn1 Or btn3
 '***************************************************************************************
'Game Buttons 2 - 16 ************************************************************
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Button Style
    Button2.ForeColor = Color.Transparent
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Button2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    Button2.Text = ""
    Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
    'Button2.Enabled = False

    'Select Case
    Select Case btn2
        Case Is = 1
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Login
            Button2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Login
            lblPicName.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication"
            lblDescript.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication, or 2FA adds an extra step to a basic log-in procedure."
        Case Is = 2
            'Content PaceHolder*****
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Cloud
            Button2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Cloud
            lblPicName.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication"
            lblDescript.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication, or 2FA adds an extra step to a basic log-in procedure."
        Case Is = 3
            'Content PaceHolder*****
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Pwmanager
            Button2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Pwmanager
            lblPicName.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication"
            lblDescript.Text = "Two - Factor Authentication, or 2FA adds an extra step to a basic log-in procedure."
        Case Is = 4
    End Select
```

The picture I have provided shows what I need to happen when I select the first button in the application.

Image to illustrate:

[image]

Once the user selects the button the photo will be displayed as the button as well as off to the right with the name and description.

Comment: Is the photo not linked?

Comment: Is there any information I am missing that could be more useful to solving this?

Comment: The code that is 'incorrect'.

Comment: Without seeing your code I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do.

Comment: Per the code above I was attempting to assign 'btn2' a random value and then using that value to select which case to use.

Comment: I think it might help to compare what you are trying to do with something more familiar. It sounds like you have over-complicated your problem somehow. Can we think about this simply as trying to shuffle some cards and lay them out in a 4x4 grid? Even if that's not exactly what you want to do, comparing what you want with this might help us to more easily understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pursue a solution that is more based on data instead of code. Your code seems to be hard-wiring a good deal of similar or duplicate logic whereas you could just store all the possibilities in a data structure and shuffle it around. Then you would only use the code to present the shuffled results.

```
Public Class Form1

   Class SecurityTip
      Public PicName As String
      Public Description As String
      Public Image As Image
   End Class

   Private TipList As SecurityTip()
   Private ButtonArray As Button()

   Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
      MyBase.OnLoad(e)
      ButtonArray = New Button() {
         Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8,
         Button9, Button10, Button11, Button12, Button13, Button14, Button15, Button16}
      For I As Integer = 0 To ButtonArray.Length - 1
         AddHandler ButtonArray(I).Click, AddressOf Button_Click
      Next
      InitializeTips()
      ShuffleTips()
   End Sub

   Public Sub InitializeTips()
      TipList = New SecurityTip() {
         New SecurityTip() With {
            .Image = My.Resources.Login,
            .PicName = "Two - Factor Authentication",
            .Description = "Two - Factor Authentication, or 2FA adds an extra step to a basic log-in procedure."},
         New SecurityTip() With {
            .Image = My.Resources.Cloud,
            .PicName = "Cloud Authentication",
            .Description = "Cloud authentication might also be referred to as federated identity or something."},
         New SecurityTip() With {
            .Image = My.Resources.Pwmanager,
            .PicName = "Password Manager",
            .Description = "Password managers help users maintain separate passwords for different sites."}
         }
   End Sub

   Public Sub ShuffleTips()
      Dim R As New Random()
      For i As Integer = 0 To TipList.Length - 1
         Dim SwapIndex = R.Next(TipList.Length)
         Dim Temp = TipList(SwapIndex)
         TipList(SwapIndex) = TipList(i)
         TipList(i) = Temp
      Next
   End Sub

   Public Sub PresentTip(Index As Integer)
      With TipList(Index)
         PictureBox1.Image = .Image
         lblPicName.Text = .PicName
         lblDescript.Text = .Description
         ButtonArray(Index).BackgroundImage = TipList(Index).Image
      End With
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      For I As Integer = 0 To ButtonArray.Length - 1
         If ButtonArray(I) Is sender Then
            PresentTip(I)
            Exit Sub
         End If
      Next
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In your statement, 

Public Sub PresentTip(Index As Integer)

How would you declare " I " for TipList(I).Image

Comment: @cfonte I think TipList(I) should have been TipList(Index). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Index worked. small issue that has arose from this my menustrip at the top of the application is showing up as duplicated

File, Edit, Exit are showing up twice and overlaying on top of the "start" button.

Comment: @cfonte I think that problem is because InitializeComponent() is being called twice. I thought when overriding OnLoad it was necessary to call it, but I was mistaken. InitializeComponent should be explicitly called if you override the form's *constructor* not the OnLoad function. Just delete `InitializeComponent()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, below

```
'Button2.Enabled = False
```

Add

```
Dim rndNum As Random
Dim randomChoice As Integer = rndNum.Next(1, 4)
```

and your select case statement to

```
Select Case randomChoice
    Case 1
    Case 2
    Case 3
    Case 4
```

including the code for each of course.